# (Excel) Comparing two row-adjacent cells in a range of two columns to find the lowest value b/t the two, then summing the results of each row-pair

Tags: excel, function, sumproduct

I'm essentially checking two adjacent row cells to determine the lowest value between them, and doing this for a range of rows in two columns, and then adding those results together in a single cell. I know this is simple enough to do with a third cheater column and the formula =MIN(A1,B1) in a separate cell for each row, and then summing that cheater column, but I would prefer NOT to have that extra cheater column and have the entire process contained in a single formula in a single cell (which I'm assuming is possible in the first place)

For example:

```
       
[Category]  [Required] [Achieved]
  AAA           2          2    
  BBB           1          9
  CCC           2          0
  DDD           2          1

[Total Required] [Actually Achieved]
       7                  4
```

Clearly you can see that while for the "Total Required" I can simply sum each value in the "Required" column, for "Actually Achieved" I cannot simply sum the values in the "Achieved" column, because the overabundance of Achievements in the BBB category throws off the total, and would make it seem as if I already had a surplus of Achievements needed to win, because it is not comparing the pairs of cells on a PER CATEGORY basis. I essentially need to 'throw away' all the extra numbers on a per category basis before I sum all the categories, as Achievements made above what is Required do not count towards the overall total.

I have tried various ways of doing this (SUMIFS, SUMPRODUCT, etc.), but I am an Excel novice and deeply unfamiliar with how nesting multiple functions and arrays work here. To me it seems like something that should be EXTREMELY simple to do but I just don't know the right way to do it. Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

SUMPRODUCT is the way to go:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B5>=C2:C5)*(C2:C5))+((B2:B5<C2:C5)*(B2:B5)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! That's exactly what I need, but if you don't mind could you break that formula down a bit and explain how/why it works? It's clear upon reading it that I don't fully understand how the SUMPRODUCT function operates.

Comment: You can step through the process by going to Evaluate Formula on the Formulas Tab.  it will show you step by step what it does.  but basically it multiplies the values in each column by TRUE/FALSE which becomes 1/0 respectively then adds the two arrays together.

Comment: I see, so it essentially compares (>=) each cell-pair and creates a string of 1s and 0s for the TRUE/FALSE results, multiplies each value in the right column by either 1 (thus keeping that value) or 0 (thus discarding that value), then does another comparison (<) and multiplies the 1/0 string by the OTHER column in order to fill in the "gaps" (0s) from the other column with values. If that's what is happening, then I think I understand it now. Thank you.

Comment: This is along the lines of how I was initially trying to do this, but then I red-herringed myself thinking that I was overthinking it and that there was a simpler way to do it with a MIN function.

Comment: @Will one note, not a string but an array of  values are created.  Other than that yes that is correct.  `*` is like `And` and `+` is like `Or`.  Also, if this answered the question please consider marking as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.